# In Laravel, How can I apply a filter on all routes of a website except one specific route?

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel PHP Framework, How can I apply a filter on all routes/pages of the website except one specific route/page?

Update:
It will be great if there is a way other than (route groups)?

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-groups Is this it?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution other than using (Route Groups).

Comment: Why don't you want to use Route Groups?  They are the obvious solution for this.

Comment: @J.T.Grimes Because I want to apply the filter on all pages of the website except only one page, I think there should be some simple and elegant way to do this, other than using (route groups).

Comment: how you going to add your filter to the routes ?

Answer (score 1):

use [`route groups`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-groups)

```
// unsecured routes.
Route::get('/', 'UserController@getLogin');

Route::group(array('before' => 'yourFilter'), function()
{
     // secured by filter `yourFilter`.

     Route::controller('route1', 'XxxController');
     Route::post('user/save', function() {
           // content
     });
     Route::get('user', 'UserController@getUser');

});
```